# Работа с ключами шифрования

Tags: java, android, криптография

Получаю открытый ключ алгоритма RSA через парсинг JSON, соответственно имею его в виде String. Собственно вопрос такой как присвоить значение ключа которые имеет тип String переменной которая имеет тип Key? Это нужно для того чтобы получить открытый ключ зашифровать из текст и отослать шифротекст обратно.
Привожу мой не рабочий код для понимания проблемы:

```
try {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(4096);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();

    Key publicKey = null;
    publicKey = who_open_key;

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("TAG", "RSA key pair error");
}
```

Ошибка в строке publicKey = who_open_key; who_open_key - String

Comment: Тег [android-studio] ставится к вопросам, которые касаются проблем в работе с самой программой, а не для демонстрации своих предпочтений а выборе средства разработки. Решение ваших вопросов никак не зависит от используемой вами IDE и данный тег в них лишний.

Comment: Ято из себя представляет класс `Key`?